# Android Notepad provider classnotfound error ing google drive sdk examples

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api

After studying the google drive quickstart from android. I downloaded their example and got this error:

```
01-13 03:38:39.039: E/AndroidRuntime(29967): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.example.android.notepad.NotePadProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.android.notepad.NotePadProvider in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.android.notepad-1.apk]
01-13 03:38:39.039: E/AndroidRuntime(29967):    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:3561)
01-13 03:38:39.039: E/AndroidRuntime(29967):    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:3313)
01-13 03:38:39.039: E/AndroidRuntime(29967):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:3269)
01-13 03:38:39.039: E/AndroidRuntime(29967):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:117)
01-13 03:38:39.039: E/AndroidRuntime(29967):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:973)
01-13 03:38:39.039: E/AndroidRuntime(29967):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-13 03:38:39.039: E/AndroidRuntime(29967):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
01-13 03:38:39.039: E/AndroidRuntime(29967):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
01-13 03:38:39.039: E/AndroidRuntime(29967):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-13 03:38:39.039: E/AndroidRuntime(29967):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-13 03:38:39.039: E/AndroidRuntime(29967):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
01-13 03:38:39.039: E/AndroidRuntime(29967):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
01-13 03:38:39.039: E/AndroidRuntime(29967):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-13 03:38:39.039: E/AndroidRuntime(29967): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.android.notepad.NotePadProvider in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.android.notepad-1.apk]
01-13 03:38:39.039: E/AndroidRuntime(29967):    at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
01-13 03:38:39.039: E/AndroidRuntime(29967):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
01-13 03:38:39.039: E/AndroidRuntime(29967):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
01-13 03:38:39.039: E/AndroidRuntime(29967):    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:3546)
01-13 03:38:39.039: E/AndroidRuntime(29967):    ... 12 more
```

I followed the instructions [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/android). What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chances are your Android version is old, as this [ContentProvider.PipeDataWriter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.PipeDataWriter.html) was added into API 11 upwards aka Honeycomb and later.

Notice the crucial line in the [sample source](https://code.google.com/p/google-drive-sdk-samples/source/browse/android/src/com/example/android/notepad/NotePadProvider.java#51)

```
public class NotePadProvider extends ContentProvider 
                            implements 
                            PipeDataWriter<Cursor> {
    // SNIP 
}
```

Looking at the [original source](https://code.google.com/p/google-drive-sdk-samples/source/browse/android/AndroidManifest.xml#30) of the sample's `AndroidManifest.xml` dictates the minimum version of the SDK required is 16 (i.e. Android Ice Cream Sandwich or later)

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" />
```

Running it on a older version of Android even if the minimum version was changed to reflect your current Android version, such as SDK 9 for Gingerbread, 8 for Froyo or 7 for Eclair, it will fail horribly with the `ClassNotFoundException` as the `ContentProvider` does not implement `PipeDataWriter` due to being non-existant in earlier versions of Android.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. Download google_play_services from SDK Manager under "extras"
2. Import /extras/google/google_play_services/libproject into your workspace (it imports as a library)
3. Delete google_play_services.jar from NotesList (the google quickstart)
4. Go to project properties > Android > add library > add google_play_services library.
5. Clean and Run

I guess there must be some kind of problem with the jar, I've just done it (I had some similar errors when I tried the pic uploading quickstart and this was the way to solve it) and it works like a charm.  Hope it helps :)